# this code got error? why i cannot use this code do the register database

Tags: asp.net

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Partial Class register
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim an As New OleDbConnection("provider=micromofy.jet.oledb.4.0;database=" & Server.MapPath("database/Database1.accdb"))

    Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click
        Try
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into reo{Name,Age,Contact,Gender,Address,Username,Password,Comfirm Password}values{a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8}", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a1", TextBox1)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a2", TextBox2)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a3", TextBox3)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a4", TextBox4)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a5", TextBox5)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a6", TextBox6)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a7", TextBox7)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a8", TextBox8)
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn.Close()
            Label1.Text = "Data Saved"
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox3.Text = ""
            TextBox4.Text = ""
            TextBox5.Text = ""
            TextBox6.Text = ""
            TextBox7.Text = ""
            TextBox8.Text = ""
        Catch ex As Exception
            cn.Close()
            Label1.text = ex.Message

        End Try


        Server.Transfer("Login.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: please post your error and reformat your code sample

Comment: There are several problems with your code. I suggest looking up a good turorial and start from there.

Answer (score 0):

If your connection string is sorted out...

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into reo (Name,Age,Contact,Gender,Address,Username,Password,[Comfirm Password]) values (@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4,@a5,@a6,@a7,@a8)", cn)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", TextBox1.Text)
```

etc.